# Plotting data by total number of elements

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I have a movie dataset that has some movies in English and other movies in other languages. I'm trying to display using an sns barplot the number of movies per language.
I tried:

```
    fig = sns.barplot(x="original_language", y=train.id.count(), data=train)
```

But this is showing a wrong result where all movies are in English while my actual data shows that I have:

32267 movies in english

13193 movies in other

What am I doing wrong? What should I aggregate on?

Comment: The barplot does the count automatically so you can leave it out: `fig = sns.barplot(x="original_language", y="id", data=train)`

Comment: @seanswe id is an int value. I tried that but it is actually considering the value of the id and calculating some sort of average

Comment: Sorry, you need to set the estimator parameter to either 'len' or 'np.sum'. If you're just counting ids, use 'len': `fig = sns.barplot(x="original_language", y="id", data=train, estimator=len)` If you need to add the values of id, set it to 'np.sum'

Comment: Yes! I set it to "len" and it worked! That is what I was missing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @seanswe in the comments above, the estimator argument was missing!

```
fig = sns.barplot(x="original_language", y="id", data=train, estimator=len)
```

Comment: Good idea to answer the question yourself, but since you decided to do so, please go for the extra mile and include the correct code snippet here in the answer (comments may always be deleted in the future).

Comment: Good! When the minimum time passes, you should come back and accept your answer